# Single row subquery returns more than one row SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get multiple rows to display on the same line. I have the follow code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  SUBSTR(JOB.JOBNAME,1,25) "Jobname",'|',
  (SELECT SUBSTR(VAR.VAREXPR,1,15) 
FROM CTMSLO80.CMS_SETVAR VAR
    WHERE var.var = '%%PS8-PRCSNAME'
      AND JOB.jobno   =  VAR.jobno) "Process",'|',
  (SELECT SUBSTR(VAR.VAREXPR,1,30) FROM CTMSLO80.CMS_SETVAR VAR
    WHERE var.var = '%%PS8-RUNCONTROLID'
      AND JOB.jobno   =  VAR.jobno) "Run Cntrl ID",'|',
  NVL((SELECT SUBSTR(VAR.VAREXPR,1,20) FROM CTMSLO80.CMS_SETVAR VAR
    WHERE var.var = '%%PS8-PRCSTYPE'
      AND JOB.jobno   =  VAR.jobno), ' ') "Process Type",'|',
  SUBSTR(DAYSCAL,1,10) "Calendar",'|',
  NVL2(JOB.FROMTIME,SUBSTR(JOB.FROMTIME,1,2)||':'||SUBSTR(JOB.FROMTIME,3,2),' ') "From",'|',
  NVL2(JOB.Until  ,SUBSTR(JOB.Until,1,2)||':'||SUBSTR(JOB.Until,3,2),' ') "Until",'|',
   Case
WHEN JOB.DAYSTR = 'ALL' THEN
JOB.DAYSTR
Else
SUBSTR(NVL(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRANSLATE(JOB.WDAYSTR,'01234567AL','0MTW4F7AL'),'0','Su'),'4','Th'),'7','Sa'),'ALL','Daily'),' '),1,16)
End
"Days",'|',
  NVL(JOB.DESCRIPT,' ') "Description",'|',
  SUBSTR (job.jobname,1,5) "Table",'|',
(SELECT SUBSTR (CON.CONDNAME,1,75) FROM CTMSLO80.CMS_CON_J CON
   WHERE CON.ROWTYPE = 'I' 
   AND JOB.JOBNO = CON.JOBNO) "In Cond",'|',
  (SELECT SUBSTR(VAR.VAREXPR,1,35) FROM CTMSLO80.CMS_SETVAR VAR
    WHERE var.var = '%%PS8-DESCRIPTION'
      AND JOB.jobno   =  VAR.jobno) "Description",'|',
  SUBSTR(JOB.OWNER,1,6) "BMCID",'|',
  NVL2(JOB.DESCRIPT,(SUBSTR(JOB.DESCRIPT,1,INSTR(JOB.DESCRIPT,'/',1,1)-1)),'1') JOBORDER
  FROM CTMSLO80.CMS_JOBDEF JOB, CTMSLO80.CMS_SETVAR VAR
      where  OWNER LIKE 'BMCHR'
      and JOB.JOBno   =  VAR.JOBno
```

The part where I run into trouble is:

```
(SELECT SUBSTR (CON.CONDNAME,1,75) FROM CTMSLO80.CMS_CON_J CON
   WHERE CON.ROWTYPE = 'I' 
   AND JOB.JOBNO = CON.JOBNO) "In Cond",'|',
```

It will return one value, but if I have multiple values to return, it will give an error "ORA-01427: Single Row Subquery returns more than one row"

I've tried various methods like XML path, IN, EXISTS, etc, but those give me different errors that I am not able to resolve. Anyone have experience with something like this?

===========================

Thank you for responses

Version if PL/SQL is 9.0.6.1655

Don't know what you mean by "Delimiter"

Not having success breaking down the code into a smaller chunk. I did not write the bulk of this code, but am trying to tweak it to work with what I am trying to do.

The link that was provided did help get rid of the error. I used the "MAX" function and changed the pertinent query to be:

```
(SELECT max(SUBSTR (CON.CONDNAME,1,75)) FROM CTMSLO80.CMS_CON_J CON
   WHERE CON.ROWTYPE = 'I' 
   AND JOB.JOBNO = CON.JOBNO) "In Cond",'|',
```

Now it will return the first item at least. However, I would like to be able to return multiple items. This part of the query returns a column that has a value like below:

In Cond

example1

There is more data to pull however, I want it to return like so:

In Cond

example1, example2

Any ideas on how I can get it to do that?

Comment: Did you try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397694/how-to-fix-ora-01427-single-row-subquery-returns-more-than-one-row-in-select

Comment: What do you expect to see if there are multiple values? Do you really want to do joins (instead of subqueries) and then use string aggregation to combine the values? (If so - which version of Oracle, and which delimiter?). Cutting your code down to a simple example, with tables and data and expected results, would really help.

Comment: This is expected behavior.  You're attempting to join on multiple separate values.  As was suggested, subqueries might be better, or if you're really only interested in the first result, you might want to change your condition to only look at the top result (this may or may not be what you're actually intending).

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: instead of `max` use `wm_concat(distinct SUBSTR (CON.CONDNAME,1,75))` or list_agg if your version supports it.  this will combine the multiple values returned to as a single separated list (provided it doesn't exceed the 4000 character limit)

Comment: `Anyone have experience with something like this?` - well, you need tell us what do you want when the subquery returns 2 or more rows. Say for example that the subquery returns: `X`, `Y`, `Z`, what is an expected result in such a case ? `X` or `Y` or `Z` ? Or maybe `XYZ` or `YZ` or `ZYX` ? We don't know what do you want to get as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LISTAGG()` if you want a list:

```
(SELECT LISTAGG(SUBSTR(CON.CONDNAME, 1, 75), '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CON.CONDNAME)
 FROM CTMSLO80.CMS_CON_J CON
 WHERE CON.ROWTYPE = 'I' AND JOB.JOBNO = CON.JOBNO
)  as "In Cond",
```

Note that the maximum size of the list is subject to Oracle limits on strings, 4,000 characters.  You might overflow if your list is too long.

Comment: YES! I was just editing it based on the last comment and had something similar to what you put, but had some errors. This answer worked for PL/SQL Oracle type database. THANK YOU ALL!!