# ora-01427 on select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query is giving me an ora-01427
I have found out what that exception is and and also some solutions on how to solve it, but just not in my case. Is there a way I can find out what rows are duplicated?

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

Here is my query:

```
    SELECT rec.*, 
    (select date_tt 
     from TREATMENT_TERMINAT tr, RECIPIENT rec
     where tr.SCANDIANUMBER = rec.SCANDIANUMBER) DATE_TT
FROM RECIPIENT rec;
```

Thanks

Comment: The subquery returns more than one date_tt

Comment: One `rec.SCANDIANUMBER` has more than one `tr.SCANDIANUMBER`. Use a `join` if you want all `tr.SCANDIANUMBER`, otherwise, you'll have to figure out how you want to condense them into a single record.

Comment: Just execute your query and figure out why it returns more than 1 row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Ora-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397694/how-to-fix-ora-01427-single-row-subquery-returns-more-than-one-row-in-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want a *correlated* subquery.  That would be:

```
select rec.*, 
       (select tr.date_tt 
        from TREATMENT_TERMINAT tr
        where tr.SCANDIANUMBER = rec.SCANDIANUMBER
       ) as DATE_TT
from RECIPIENT rec;
```

Note the removal of `RECIPIENT` from the subquery.

If the above returns the same problem, then here are three solutions:

- Add `and rownum = 1` to the `where` clause.
- Change the `select` to `select max(date_tt)`.
- Use `listagg()` to get all values:  `select listagg(date_tt, ',') within group (order by date_tt)`.

To find the problem rows, use a `group by`.  The following gets all duplicates:

```
select tr.SCANDIANUMBER 
from TREATMENT_TERMINAT tr
group by tr.SCANDIANUMBER
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I want to do. But the solution you suggest throws the same error as mine :-)

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this?

```
select date_tt, COUNT(*) AS RC 
     FROM RECIPIENT rec
     LEFT JOIN tr ON tr.SCANDIANUMBER = rec.SCANDIANUMBER
GROUP BY date_tt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an explicit join, possibly left if there is the possibility of not being a matching `date_tt`, and just return the column.

```
SELECT rec.*, 
       DATE_TT
FROM RECIPIENT rec
left join tr
on tr.SCANDIANUMBER = rec.SCANDIANUMBER
;
```

Old style joins are outdated, please take the person who taught you to comma join, insert them into a cannon, and fire them into the sun.

Comment: thank you John, you make me smile... :-)  I agree with you (the first part of the sentence, not the second one...)