# Sql and oracle apex, "single-row subquery returns more than one row"-error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex-5.1

This is my query. I want to show differences between price on different dates.

```
 select
       id,
       PRODUCT,
       PRICE,
       P_DATE,
(SELECT(t2.price - t1.price) AS PRICE_DIFF
FROM PRODUCT_TABLE t1 CROSS JOIN
     PRODUCT_TABLE t2
WHERE t1.p_date = '11-DEC-17' AND t2.p_date = '12-DEC-17' AND t1.id=t2.id) as PRICE_DIFF
  from PRODUCT_TABLE
```

This is the error I get:

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

How can I avoid that error?

Comment: Please take into account that links can get lost, making this question useless for future users. Because of that many readers will consider the question off-topic for the content of what you actually posted here. Which is largely nothing.

Comment: please change your query to `select
       id,
       PRODUCT,
       PRICE,
       P_DATE,
(SELECT max(t2.price - t1.price) AS nav_return
FROM pivot_table t2
WHERE t1.p_date = '11-DEC-17' AND t2.p_date = '12-DEC-17' AND t1.id=t2.id) as nav_retun
  from PIVOT_TABLE t1`
 like to get the result

Comment: Could you copy your table structure?

Comment: A CROSS JOIN in a subquery is guaranteed to always return too many rows unless those two tables only have a single row each. That's never going to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Ora-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397694/how-to-fix-ora-01427-single-row-subquery-returns-more-than-one-row-in-select)

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work for you?

Setup:

```
with product_table as
(
select 1 as id, 'cheese' as product, 1000 as price, TO_DATE('11-DEC-17', 'DD-MON-YY') as p_date from dual
union all
select 1, 'cheese', 1100,  TO_DATE('12-DEC-17', 'DD-MON-YY') from dual
union all
select 2, 'onion', 500, TO_DATE('11-DEC-17', 'DD-MON-YY') from dual
union all
select 2, 'onion', 550, TO_DATE('12-DEC-17', 'DD-MON-YY') from dual
)
```

Query:

```
select
    t1.id,
    t1.product,
    t1.price,
    t1.p_date,  -- maybe t2.p_date? not sure which is relevant
    t2.price - t1.price as price_diff
from
    product_table t1
inner join
    product_table t2
on t1.id = t2.id
where
    t1.p_date = '11-DEC-17'
and t2.p_date = '12-DEC-17'
```

Output:

```
        ID PRODUCT      PRICE P_DATE    PRICE_DIFF
---------- ------- ---------- --------- ----------
         1 cheese        1000 11-DEC-17        100
         2 onion          500 11-DEC-17         50
```