# need to look through many records of one table for each one in another

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In Oracle SQL Developer, I get the error, "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" when I try to run this line of code.

```
UPDATE stream_log sl 
set recordnum = 
    (SELECT recordnum 
     FROM STREAM_LOG_HISTORY slh 
     WHERE substr(slh.recordnum, 2, 5) = sl.recordnum);
```

In order to try to fix it, I tried changing my code to this:

```
UPDATE stream_log sl 
set recordnum = 
    (SELECT recordnum 
     FROM STREAM_LOG_HISTORY slh 
     WHERE substr(slh.recordnum, 2, 5) = sl.recordnum).first;
```

but it says the period is syntactically erroneous.

I need to retrieve the first character of strings that match the last 5 of the given one, but to do that I need to look through many records of one table for each one in another.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to limit your sub query to return just 1 row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Ora-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397694/how-to-fix-ora-01427-single-row-subquery-returns-more-than-one-row-in-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to retrieve the first character of strings that match the last
>   5 of the given one,

The "first character"  that matches  cannot be guaranteed to be a particular string, every time you run the `update`, unless you have any other unique column which could be used to order the results, preferably using `row_number()` or `FIRST_VALUE` functions. So, other option is to use `MAX` or `MIN` to get a single record for each match.

```
UPDATE stream_log sl
SET recordnum = (
        SELECT MAX(recordnum)
        FROM stream_log_history slh
        WHERE Substr(slh.recordnum, 2, 5) = sl.recordnum
        );
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I'm sorry for the late response.  I don't think that will work, because recordnum is a string (poorly named, I know).  That's why I'm using substring.  Originally recordnum was a 6 character string, but I lopped off the first character.  So I need to select from history where the last 5 characters match, to get back the first character.   EDIT: It worked, thank you!  I see MAX and MIN work with string functions too.  Thank you for your help :)  I tried upvoting but then it resets to 0.