# Counting the number of days an employee is expected to report for work between their start and end dates

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am using Oracle 12c.

I am looking to count the number of days an employee is expected to report to work, to ultimately report each department's absentee rate per quarter. I've already cobbled together a virtual table with each department's absentee person-days to which I would like to join the department's expected person-days (if a department has 3 employees, then a 5 day work week has 3 x 5 = 15 person-days).

I have a `CALENDAR` table that tells me if a department is open; an 'x' in the `IS_OPEN` field indicates that the department is open and all its employees are expected to report for work, anything else means the department is closed.

```
CALENDAR(
    DEPT_ID VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
    QUARTER VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
    CALENDAR_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    IS_OPEN VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL
)
```

```
DEPT_ID | QUARTER | CALDR_DATE | IS_OPEN
--------|---------|------------|---------
ACCTING | 2019Q1  | 2019-03-02 | ' '
MFGING  | 2019Q1  | 2019-03-02 | x
MRKTING | 2019Q1  | 2019-03-02 | ' '
ACCTING | 2019Q1  | 2019-03-03 | x
MFGING  | 2019Q1  | 2019-03-03 | x
MRKTING | 2019Q1  | 2019-03-03 | x
ACCTING | 2019Q1  | 2019-03-04 | x
MFGING  | 2019Q1  | 2019-03-04 | x
MRKTING | 2019Q1  | 2019-03-04 | x
...
```

I also have a `TRANSACTIONS` table that tells me an employee's start date and end date (`TRANS_TYPE` 4 is a start date, `TRANS_TYPE` 5 is an end date).

```
TRANSACTIONS(
    DEPT_ID VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
    QUARTER VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
    TRANSACTION_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    TRANSACTION_TYPE NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL,
    EMPLOYEE_ID VARCHAR2(13) NOT NULL
)
```

```
DEPT_ID | QUARTER | TRANS_DATE | TRANS_TYPE | EMPLOYEE_ID
--------|---------|------------|------------|------------
...
MFGING  | 2019Q1  | 2019-01-07 |          4 | 123
MRKTING | 2019Q1  | 2019-01-28 |          4 | 456
MFGING  | 2019Q1  | 2019-02-01 |          5 | 123
...
```

In the above table, employee 123 started work on 7 January and left the department on 1 February. Employee 456 started on 28 January and is still in that department today.

**Not obvious from the above example**: any employee that was a member of a department in the previous quarter will automatically get a `TRANS_TYPE` 4 when they show up for work on the first day of the quarter (they don't get a `TRANS_TYPE` 5 on the last day of the previous quarter).

I would like to join these two tables such that the resulting virtual table has the following fields: `DEPT_ID`, `QUARTER`, `CALDR_DATE`, `EMPLOYEE_ID`, `ATTENDANCE_EXPECTED`, `DEPT_IS_OPEN` (optional), where the `ATTENDANCE_EXPECTED` field contains a '1' if the employee is expected to report for work that day (ie, the department is open and the `CALDR_DATE` is between the employee's start date and end date or `SYSDATE` if no end date exists).

I can then `SUM(ATTENDANCE_EXPECTED)` (or possibly `COUNT(*)` after filtering for `DEPT_IS_OPEN`) from the resulting table, and group by `DEPT_ID`, `QUARTER` to get the number of person-days for each department and quarter.

I can't figure out how to expand the rows so that I have one row per employee per day for every day from their start date to their end date (or current date if there is no end date).

How do I do this, or is there a better way to count person-days per department per quarter?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you handling vacations, sick days, holidays, jury duty, and other reasons why an employee would not report for work, but would not be "absent"?

Comment: My 'count_absences' query is working well; we have different codes for different types of absences and only certain codes are included in the calculation. This will affect the number of `ATTENDANCE_EXPECTED` days, but the error should be negligibly small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work

Explained:
- Find all open days for department, closed days are of no interest
- Join all employees/transactions for that department if
---  calender date >= trans date with type 4
---  and calender_date < trans date with type 5
- An employee in an apartment IS a transaction with type 4 in the transaction table

```
select c.DEPT_ID, c.QUARTER, c.CALENDAR_DATE, e.EMPLOYEE_ID, 1 ATTENDANCE_EXPECTED, c.IS_OPEN
from calendar c, 
     transactions e
where c.dept_id = e.dept_id
  and c.quarter = e.quarter
  and c.IS_OPEN = 'x'
  and e.transaction_type = 4
  and c.calendar_date < NVL((select transaction_date from transactions where dept_id = e.dept_id and Employee_Id = e.employee_id and quarter = e.quarter and transaction_type = 5),sysdate)
  and c.calendar_date >= (select transaction_date from transactions where dept_id = e.dept_id and Employee_Id = e.employee_id and quarter = e.quarter and transaction_type = 4);
```

Comment: This solution worked for the most part. When I ran it against my actual data, it gave me an '`ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`' error, but after applying [hashbrown's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21397840/11192831) to both sub-queries, it worked nicely. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select c.DEPT_ID, c.QUARTER, 
       c.CALENDAR_DATE, 
       e.EMPLOYEE_ID, 
       case when c.CALENDAR_DATE between 
                    e.TRANSACTION_DATE and NVL(t.TRANSACTION_DATE, c.CALENDAR_DATE)  
        then 1 else 0 end ATTENDANCE_EXPECTED, 
       CASE when c.IS_OPEN = 'x' then 1 else 0 end is_open
from calendar c 
LEFT JOIN transactions e 
       ON c.dept_id = e.dept_id
      and c.quarter = e.quarter
      and e.transaction_type = 4
left JOIN transactions t 
       ON t.transaction_type = 5
      and t.EMPLOYEE_ID = e.EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

More rows for view, here you can filter and count non_open days [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d7114c71894defc35d98f4e7f8a2370b)